# Set property of NumericStepper declared as UIComponent

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface

I have a NumericStepper declared as a UIComponent:

```
<![CDATA[
private var component:UIComponent;
component = new NumericStepper();
]]>
```

I need to change the .maximum value of the NumericStepper but due to the UIComponent not having a .maximum property the following code fails with the error: *1119: Access of possibly undefined property maximum through a reference with static type mx.core:UIComponent*.

```
component.maximum = 11;
```

My question is how would I define a property in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it using the dynamic/string syntax:

```
component["maximum"] = 11;
```

I use that a lot, the only downsides are:

- decreased performance ([3-5x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269628/what-is-faster-plain-objects-or-strongly-typed-objects-in-actionscript/2270843#2270843)), but considering it only takes 0.001ms at most to set a property, that doesn't matter.
- no compile-time checking, so Flex Builder won't throw any errors until runtime

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you can use is "casting":

```
var component:UIComponent;
component = new NumericStepper;
(component as NumericStepper).maximum = 500;
```

This has compile-time checking, but i don't know if it has any "downsides"
Hope this helps.